# How do i get my discord bot to play an audio file from my computer

Tags: python-3.x, voice, discord.py

I am trying to get my bot to play an audio file in the voice chat, not a youtube video. I surprisingly can't really find any working help on this.

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        await ctx.send("Specify something then")
    else:
        #server = ctx.message.server
        #voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)

        voice_player = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()

        if args[0] == "chulp":
            print("Playing chulp")
            source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("Core files\\Sounds\\chulpy.mp3")
            player = voice_player.play(source)
            player.start()
```

I always get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Comment: `play` doesn't return anything, it should just start playing the file.  If you remove the `player.start()` line, what happens?

Comment: it doesnt change anything